# Сумма зарплат всех подчиненных (WITH RECURSIVE)

Tags: sql, рекурсия, дерево

Исходная таблица:

```
create table test_table (
id integer not null,
name char(1) not null,
parent_id integer,
sum integer not null);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(1, 'A', null, 300);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(11, 'B', 1, 2340);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(111, 'C', 11, 3200);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(22, 'D', 1, 7540);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(2, 'E', null, 6300);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(3, 'F', 2, 8600);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(101, 'G', 3, 3800);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(102, 'H', 3, 9700);
```

Вот код:

```
WITH sum_bum ( sum, id, parent_id ) AS (
  SELECT 0, id, parent_id
  FROM   test_table
  WHERE  parent_id is NULL
     UNION ALL
  SELECT s.sum + t.sum, t.id, t.parent_id
  FROM test_table t
       INNER JOIN
       sum_bum s
       ON ( s.id = t.parent_id )
  )
SELECT s.sum, ttt.name FROM sum_bum s join test_table ttt on ttt.id = s.id
order by ttt.name;
```

Пример выходных значений:

```
 13080 - А
 3200 -  B
 NULL -  C
 NULL -  D
 22100 - E
 13500 - F
 NULL -  G
 NULL -  H
```

По-хорошему, он должен считать зарплату всех подчиненных, но считает зарплату только тех, у кого есть начальники. Т.е. все наоборот

Comment: без структуры и примера таблицы лень разбираться в вашем запросе, чтобы понять где там у вас ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно посчитать сумму только для корневых записей, то пишите так:

```
WITH sum_bum (id, root_id ) AS (
  SELECT id, id as root_id
  FROM   test_table
  WHERE  parent_id is NULL
     UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, s.root_id
  FROM test_table t
       INNER JOIN
       sum_bum s
       ON ( s.id = t.parent_id )
  )
SELECT ttt.name, sum(ttt1.sum) 
FROM sum_bum s 
        join test_table ttt on ttt.id = s.root_id
        join test_table ttt1 on ttt1.id = s.id
where s.id != s_root_id
group by ttt.name
order by ttt.name;
```

Смысл в том, что вам нужно определить корневого сотрудника для каждого из дочерних (независимо от уровня иерархии) и потом просто просуммировать их зарплаты. Поскольку считать надо только зарплаты подчиненных, в условии where убираем строку с самим сотрудником.

Comment: Это почти то, что нужно. Необходимо найти зарплаты подчиненных всех работников, у которых есть подчиненные. Но это я уже сам попробую реализовать

Comment: @daydark, просто уберите из первой части рекурсивного cte фильтр "WHERE  parent_id is NULL" - тогда подчиненные будут искаться для всех сотрудников, а не только для корневых. Ну и немножко надо сам финальный запрос поменять, чтобы для сотрудников без подчиненных выводились null (в текущем запросе они просто не будут выводиться - будут отсекаться условием "where s.id != s_root_id"

Comment: чего-то с финальным запросом не вкурил

Comment: @daydark, вот так попробуйте: 
SELECT ttt.name, sum(ttt1.sum) 
FROM sum_bum s 
        join test_table ttt on ttt.id = s.root_id
        left join test_table ttt1 on ttt1.id = s.id and s.id != s_root_id 
group by ttt.name
order by ttt.name;

Comment: Да, получилось, спасибо)